# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \ln^m x\ln^n(1+x){\rm d}x$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{N^+}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> Find $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 \ln^m x\ln^n (1+x){\rm
>  d}x$$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{N^+}.$

Comment: Hint: $0 \leq \ln(1+x)\leq \ln{2} < 1$.

Comment: @Mindlack This probably can not work, because the bounds are too excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I would do is elaborate on Hint: 0≤ln(1+x)≤ln2<1
And I would ask for your pardon as I am not yet in grasp with Latex inline notation. So, I would simply resort to posting an image.
[Solution to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6PG3.jpg)

Thus, from sandwich theorem/ sqeeze play answer is 0.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you. I am beginning to get some hang of it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint of @Mindlack, we have

\begin{align*} 0\leq\left|\int_0^1 \ln^m x\ln^n(1+x){\rm d}x\right|\le&\int_0^1|\ln^m n\ln^n(1+x)|{\rm d}x\\ \le&\ln^n 2\cdot\int_0^1 |\ln^m x|{\rm d}x\\ =&m!\ln^n 2 \rightarrow 0(n \to \infty)\end{align*}